# send shipping options to paypal from rails application

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

i can't send shipping options to paypal with rest api sdk

This is @payment.error.inspect

```
{
  "name"=>"VALIDATION_ERROR",
  "details"=>[
    {
      "field"=>"payer.payer_info.phone",
      "issue"=>"This field currently not supported in this request" },
    {
      "field"=>"payer.payer_info.first_name",
      "issue"=>"Not valid to specify this field in a request" },
    {
      "field"=>"payer.payer_info.last_name",
      "issue"=>"Not valid to specify this field in a request" },
    {
      "field"=>"payer.payer_info.email",
      "issue"=>"This field currently not supported in this request" },
    {
      "field"=>"payer.payer_info.shipping_address",
      "issue"=>"Not valid to specify this field in a request" }
  ],
  "message"=>"Invalid request - see details",
  "information_link"=>"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR",
  "debug_id"=>"2139ec6f8c916"
}
```

when i do:

```
shipping_address = {
  recipient_name: self.order.fullname,
  type: self.order.address_type,
  line1: self.order.street1,
  line2: self.order.street2,
  city: self.order.city,
  country_code: self.order.country_code,
  postal_code: self.order.zip,
  state: self.order.state,
  phone: self.order.phone_number }
payer_info = {
  email: self.order.email,
  first_name: self.order.fullname.split(" ").first,
  last_name: self.order.fullname.split(" ").last,
  phone: self.order.phone_number,
  shipping_address: shipping_address }

self.payment = Payment.new({
  :intent =>  "sale",
  :payer =>  {
    :payment_method =>  "paypal",
    :payer_info => payer_info },
  :redirect_urls => {
    :return_url => return_url,
    :cancel_url => cancel_url },
  :transactions =>  [{
    :item_list => {
      :shipping_address => shipping_address,
      :items => self.order.order_items.map do |item|
        {
          :name => _("T-shirts %{size} size") % {size: item.size},
          :sku => "item",
          :price => self.order.campaign.price_for_size(item.size),
          :currency => "HKD",
          :quantity => item.count,
          :amount => item.price
        }
      end},
    :amount =>  {
      :total =>  self.order.price,
      :currency =>  "HKD" },
    :description =>  _("This is the payment transaction description.") }]})

self.payment.create
self.payment.error.inspect
```

i'm use paypal-rest-sdk and need to send information about buyer to paypal for precomplete fields with address and buyer information.

how to send to paypal shipping address and payer_info ?

Answer (score 1):

When your payment_method is "paypal", the payer_info object is pre-filled. payer_info only needs to be submitted when payment_method is credit_card